# Cocoadialog dropdown with array as list

Tags: bash

Why is the foo element not included?

```
items=(  "invisible below" foo "invisible above" "bar" "foo" not invisible )
# invisible:                ^
CocoaDialog standard-dropdown --text "Choose:" --items "${items[@]}" --string-output --float --debug
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that CocoaDialog loads the list of values into an array in which the keys and values are the same. It essentially sees foo and "foo" as them same item, the second one will overwrite the first - much like an array in PHP.

So, if you change your array to this:

```
items=(  "invisible below" foo1 "invisible above" "bar" "foo" not invisible )
```

You'll see that foo1 shows up:

[image http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/6738/screenshot20110818at223.png](http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/6738/screenshot20110818at223.png)

The reason we know that it is CocoaDialog and not bash is that we can print out the array of items:

```
$ items=(  "invisible below" foo "invisible above" "bar" "foo" not invisible )

$ printf "%s\n" "${items[@]}"
invisible below
foo
invisible above
bar
foo
not
invisible
```

So, the array that you're passing is fine - CocoaDialog is just overwriting the first value with the second one.

Comment: That's actually a quite nice feature :P Thank you very much

Comment: Yes it is! I actually found your question when I was looking for a way to have multiple items listed in a multi-select. But I don't think CocoaDialog has that feature - at least not that I know of.

Comment: If you don't want to many copies of the same item, couldn't you just add an extra space to the name?

Comment: Yes you could. I also e-mailed the author of CocoaDialog and he said he might add in the multi-select thing I was looking for. :)